# Git push is not pushing css to Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am working on my first rails app. I have deployed it on heroku, git push is not pushing the css files/settings, what do i do? What could have gone wrong? (css is working locally)

EDIT: This is the output of cat .gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp
```

Comment: make sure your git ignore file is proper and the css file is not under that

Comment: I think you should check your .gitignore file.

Comment: Check your SSH certificate as well. If you pushed from one PC and then trying to push from another, it could fail if cert is not present

Comment: @zaratustra please check the edit section .. thanks

Comment: @ZaafarMehmood, the other files get pushed well, you are struggling only with the css files, right? Can you push other files from the directory where the css files are located?

Comment: @zaratustra thats right.. I have tried pushing the complete app folder at once and one by one, every change (except css/layout changes) is working

Comment: @ZaafarMehmood did you commit those files (`git add ccs_file && git commit -m "css files"`)? What branch are you trying to push? Are the commits presented in the history (`git log`) of the branch that you are trying to push?

Comment: @zaratustra yup (git log) is showing all the commits i made.

Comment: @ZaafarMehmood execute `git log YOUR_CURRENT_BRANCH..origin/YOUR_CURRENT_BRANCH` does it show anything?

Comment: @zaratustra                  fatal: ambiguous argument 'YOUR_CURRENT_BRANCH..origin/YOUR_CURRENT_BRANCH': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: @ZaafarMehmood you need to change YOUR_CURRENT_BRANCH to the name of you branch